# How do I generate all possible words of a regular expression with the following rules and syntax?

Tags: python, regex, algorithm

How do I generate all possible words of a regular expression with the following rules and syntax:

- the user inputs the alphabet;
- the user inputs the expression;
- any character that's not ()*+ or space can be part of the alphabet;
- the + character chooses between the character or sequence on its left or the one on its right;
- the * character allows one or more repetitions of the character or sequence on its left;
- two alphabetic characters in sequence will be concatenated;
- parentheses may change precedence.

I'm getting alphabet and expression as strings from user, and casting it to python lists. Then I proceed some simple validation tests on both, based on the rules above.

After that, currently, my algorithm already generates correctly the words of expressions WITHOUT parentheses. And here's my problem: I haven't found yet a way to manage parentheses properly to correctly generate the words. As I see, I have two options:

1) find a way to calculate the possible words directly from the original expression, or

2) somehow eliminate all the parentheses and have my current algorithm to solve it.

I wonder if I can get the first option done using some kind of recursive function, although I still don't know how. Any thoughts?

Here's the code so far (sorry for comments in portuguese, brazilian here):

```
alphabetInput = input(
    "Informe os caracteres do alfabeto (OBS.: os símbolos '(', ')', '+' e '*' são caracteres reservados):\n")
alphabetInput = alphabetInput.strip()  # remove os espaços em branco da string
alphabetInput = list(alphabetInput)  # transforma a string numa lista

# remove as duplicidades do alfabeto
alphabet = []
for c in alphabetInput:
    if c not in alphabet:
        alphabet.append(c)

for c in alphabet:
    if c in "()*+":
        print("Alfabeto inválido (OBS.: os símbolos '(', ')', '+' e '*' são caracteres reservados).")
        exit()

expression = input("Informe a expressão regular:\n")
expression = expression.strip()  # remove os espaços em branco da string
expression = list(expression)  # converte a string numa lista

counter = 0  # controle dos parênteses abertos e fechados no loop a seguir

for c in (expression):
    if c == "(":
        counter = counter + 1  # +1 significa que um parêntese foi aberto
    elif c == ")":
        counter = counter - 1  # -1 significa que um parêntese foi fechado
    else:
        pass
    if counter < 0:
        print("Expressão inválida. Um parêntese foi fechado sem ter sido aberto antes.")
        exit()

# se o contador for maior do que zero, significa que há mais parênteses abertos do que fechados
# se for menor do que zero, terá caído no 'if' dentro do loop acima
# se for igual a zero, estará ok
if counter > 0:
    print("Expressão inválida: Existem parênteses em aberto.")
    exit()

# testa a validade da expressão com base na existência sequências inválidas de caracteres
if (expression[0] == "+" or expression[len(expression) - 1] == "+"):  # testa a existência de "+" no começo e no fim da expressão
    print("Expressão inválida: Existem adições lógicas (+) sem um dos operandos.")
    exit()
else:
    for i in range(0, len(expression)):
        if (expression[i] == "+"):
            if (expression[i + 1] == "+" or expression[i + 1] == "*" or expression[i + 1] == ""):
                print("Expressão inválida: Existem adições lógicas (+) sem um dos operandos.")
                exit()

#### FIM DA SEÇÃO 1 ####

#### SEÇÃO 2: TESTE DE PERTINÊNCIA DOS SÍMBOLOS INFORMADOS AO ALFABETO INFORMADO ####

# OBS.: 'expression' já é uma lista, o casting é feito para que o conteúdo modificado em uma não o seja na outra
testExpression = list(expression)

# os loops seguintes marcam e removem os espaços em branco e caracteres especiais da expressão,
# e em seguida testam se os símbolos usados pertencem ao dicionário informado
for i in range(len(testExpression)):
    if testExpression[i] in " ()+*":
        testExpression[i] = "marked"

while "marked" in testExpression:
    testExpression.remove("marked")

# testa se os símbolos usados fazem parte do alfabeto informado
for c in testExpression:
    counter = 0
    for cc in alphabet:
        if c == cc:
            counter += 1;
    if counter == 0:
    # se esse contador for igual a zero, significa que não há correspondência entre o símbolo da expressão e o alfabeto
        print("Expressão informada possui símbolos que não pertencem ao alfabeto.")
        exit()

#### FIM DA SEÇÃO 2 ####

#### SEÇÃO 3: GERAÇÃO DAS PALAVRAS ####

possibilities = [[]]  # vetor que receberá os subvetores com cada possiblilidade
possibilitiesCounter = 0  # contador de possibilidades, toda vez que ele é incrementado um novo subvetor é criado

# monta e arranja as palavras geradas no vetor 'possibilities'
for i in range(0, len(expression)):
    if expression[i] in alphabet:
        possibilities[possibilitiesCounter].append(expression[i])
    if expression[i] == "+":
        possibilities.append([])
        possibilitiesCounter += 1

# imprime todas as palavras geradas na tela
yetAnotherCounter = 0
words = []  # lista final das palavras
for l in possibilities:
    words.append("".join(str(x) for x in l))
    print("Palavra ", yetAnotherCounter + 1, ":", words[yetAnotherCounter])
    yetAnotherCounter += 1
```

Comment: Sounds like the algorithm isn't fully aware of the rules.. neither of the two options seem appropriate to solving it: 1) isn't that one of the requirements anyway? (consider that each sub-expression inside a group is itself a complete regular expression, possibly itself qualified) and 2) the parenthesis are vital to correct handling of the input.

Comment: Posting your current code might help. Also, how complex can the user's regex be? Are they allowed to use `(?=positive lookahead)`, `(?:non-capturing groups)`, etc.? Check the following doc (for Python 2) if you're not perfectly up-to-date on regexes: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html

Comment: `*` will generate infinity of variants, how you plan to stop algorithm?

Comment: @P.Ax Whether or not you use the Python library for regexes, you have to choose what's the allowed syntax for the regexes that your user inputs. That's why I gave you the link to the Python doc for regexes, assuming that maybe you'd like to consider all the possibilities that Python regexes offer. But then I don't know your context, so maybe you want to only permit a very simplified syntax, with only `*+?` quantifiers and parentheses?

Comment: @TanguyP, I haven't used the python regex library because all I could find about is was ways to check if certain strings match to a regular expression. That's not the goal here; what I want is to generate every possible matcheable word from a regular expression.

Comment: @TanguyP Exactly, it's a very simple syntax: Only +*() as reserved characters

Comment: I've put the code on the post.

Comment: I believe there's a misunderstanding here. I see that you don't allow the user's expression to end with a "+" (though it is legit for a regex), and - as I can read Portuguese - I see that you really intended it this way, because when the expression does end with a "+" you print the following error message: "Invalid expression: There are logical additions (+) with one of the operands missing". But that's not how the `+` works in a regex... Are you sure what your user types is indeed a regex?

Comment: @TanguyP Yes I'm sure. I guess you're thinking that I am using the python library for regex (like, import re on beginning of code, and re.findall(<some expression here>) which is not the case. What I am doing here is, based on a particular syntax (" + " for xor between operands, " * " for repetition and " ( " and " ) " for precedence control), I establish a expression from which I want all possible combinations.

Comment: @user2864740 By saying "eliminate all parentheses" I mean to get rid of them algebraically, as in (a+b)(c+d), getting rid of parentheses, would become ac+ad+bc+bd.

Comment: @P.Ax Then go for it (although I don't think the shown forms are equivalent..)

Comment: @user2864740 With the given syntax, they are equivalent.

Comment: I did understand that you're not using Python to do some regex parsing. But from what I understand, you've been using the term "regular expression" incorrectly from the start. You want to generate all possible strings matching a given _pattern_, but your pattern is not a regular expression (at least, not any regex flavour that I know of). In a regex, `+` is a unary operator applying to the preceding character/group (e.g. `a+` matches one or more `a` letters); while in your pattern, you're using it as a binary operator which seems to have an arithmetical meaning (e.g. `a+b`).

Comment: @TanguyP By definition, if I have an sequence of characters that describes a search pattern, I have a regular expression. Even if it's not as complex as the ones we find on programming languages' libraries nowadays, the rules I described here can be considered as regular expression syntax.

Comment: Ok my bad, I read your rules too quickly, assuming that they were just a simplification of the usual regex flavours found in most programming languages/search tools, but they're not.

Answer (score 1):

So, I came to a solution by using a library called `exrex`: https://github.com/asciimoo/exrex

It has a function `generate` which does exactly what I wanted.